# MicrosoftGraph Microsoft Teams API issue

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-teams

Whenever I try to exceute the query `https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/me/joinedTeams` I get the following error in the Graph Explorer:

```
Failed to parse MS Graph backend response for request GetUserGroupsRequest. 
 Request Url: https://graph.microsoft.com/edu/me/memberOf/$/microsoft.graph.group?$filter=groupTypes/any(c:c+eq+'Unified')&$top=999, 
 Request Method: GET. 

The response is invalid, cannot convert to type IList`1Error converting value {null} to type 'System.DateTime'. 
Path 'value[0].renewedDateTime', line 1, position 2039.
```

A screenshot of from the Graph Explorer:
[image: Graph explorer]

Comment: Hi Stephan, Can you please include the request id and the timestamp?

Comment: Hi, of course:

            "request-id": "e27e646f-7579-4160-b683-f7a406558524",
            "date": "2017-11-07T08:39:11"

Comment: Any news on this one?

Comment: This should be working fine now.

Answer (score 0):

Same here. Seems that new Teams Powershell is working fine when running Get-Team command (which is calling same /beta/me/joinedTeams API)

Comment: Unfortunately the Get-Team is not working for me as well :(

Comment: Not working for me to. Worked with graph explorer but not calling through ajax call or using postman